# How to handle the event when long-press windows key on wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I' using pure cpp.

when long-press windows key, it will appear voice assistant, but d3d thread will not pause.
for my app is an game, i wanna pause game when voice assistant is appear, I don't find the api for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the code on Win8 Official demo, it works on Wp8.

**Pseudocode**:

```
CoreApplicationView->Activated += OnActivated;

void OnActivated(CoreApplicationView^ applicationView, IActivatedEventArgs^ args)
{
    CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Activated += OnWindowActivationChanged;
}

void OnWindowActivationChanged
(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^,Windows::UI::Core::WindowActivatedEventArgs^ args)
{
    CoreWindowActivationState newState = args->WindowActivationState;
    if (newState == CoreWindowActivationState::Deactivated)
    {
        DEACTIVATE code
    }
    else if (newState == CoreWindowActivationState::CodeActivated
    || newState == CoreWindowActivationState::PointerActivated)
    {
        ACTIVATE code
    }
}
```